# Sharepoint 2013 Alternate Access Mapping and HTTP Redirect

Tags: 2013, web-part, url, alternate-access-mapping, redirect

We are having trouble getting Alternate Access Mapping / HTTP Redirecting to work.

Our SP url is something like this http: //SPServer /sites/intranet

we are trying to enable users to access it through http://intranet .website.com

We would like for them to be able to access the 'intranet' page from anywhere as long as they authenticate. (Sorry for the spaces in the URL's).

We have set intranet.website.com in AAM and added bindings in IIS and then added a http redirect to http:// intranet.website.com /sites/intranet and we end up with some really strange behavior. We will load the site and it will only "partially load", for example we have a page that has a Calendar, a links list, and a corporate announcements list. The calendar loads but the links and corporate announcements web part will only show the title of the webpart and no content. The ribbon the quick links lists become non functional (I can't edit them). It pretty much makes the site useless. We've read the technet articles and other forum posts and follow suggestions but it never seems to fully function. It will work on my computer and a coworkers computer, but seemingly randomly not on other machines or in other browsers like Chrome.

We are near wits end, any help is much appreciated.

I tried to include as much detail as I could, though admittedly I am a sharepoint newb. I'm happy to provide more information if you need it, I just may need a little bit of guidance :)

---

This worked in my 2013 environment.
Create two Alternate Access Mappings. One for http://sharepointname.domain.com as the Intranet Zone and the other http://sharepointname as the Custom Zone.
Now users get the same content from either http://sharepointname/subiste/page or http://sharepointname.domain.com/subiste/page

---

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you miss-use the AAM.
AAM are intended to set different absolute URL, but keeping all relative URL the same.
SP uses two kinds od URLs in  links, dynamic JavaScript code, etc: absolute URL (e.g. http://server/sites/site01) and relative URLs (e.g. /sites/site01).

AAM are needed for SP for it to know two or more base addresses can be used with the SharePoint. This helps SP generating the correct absolute URL in dynamic scripts.

Relative URL however cannot be changed/overwritten...

There's one thing you can do, but this would require re-recreating your site collection (or backup/restore the existing one, `Retore-SPSite` has the `HostHeaderWebApplication` option for this, see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ff607788.aspx): you may use "host-named site collections", that achieves exactly your needs, i.e. creating a site collection as a new host name, see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424952.aspx.
In that case, remove the AAM you previously created, but keep bindings in IIS.